# Get tags from question through an answer

Tags: feature-request, api, tags, answers

I'd like to use this function:  [/users/{ids}/answers](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-users)  to get a list of answers from a user.

The key element that I need though is what the question was tagged as, is there a possibility of having this added to the API to avoid have to then query the questions?